# Approach for testing against mysql DB - integration tests

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pytest

Looking for advice for integration tests of data sent to DB.
I'm using `sqlalchemy` as a DB client and not sure what would be the best practice for testing:

1. Should I use a real `mysql` DB using docker image for testing purposes with the exact schema of production? Each test will put prerequisite data in DB in an input `pytest` `fixture`, and clean up at the end of the test.
2. Using some DB mocking service such as this one: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html

If somebody had experience with both options or have another one I will be glad to hear pros and cons from your view.

Answer (score 0):

Real DB.

Pros:

1. The most real and accurate test possible.
2. taking into account DB and library versions.
3. Also taking into account possible bugs.
4. New versions can be tested as they released.

Cons:

1. A lot of configurations and code is needed to set everything.
2. Very slow especially the docker build part.

DB mocker:

Pros:

1. Much faster.
2. Less configuration so easier to reconfigure if needed.

Cons:

1. There are differences between the library and the real thing.
2. New versions are lacking behind the real version.
3. Will not simulate bugs in a real specific library version.
4. If there is a bug in the mock library, you may assume that it is a bug in the real library as well or you will have to write your test in a less prefetrable way.

Bottom line:

There is no worce than devoting the time to write high quality tests that do not represent the real world. The purpose of the tests is to give confidence to the code that is being tested.  This is done by running the code in an as real environment as possible so the first option is a must in a test. The second option gives less confidence that the first option but it is much faster so it can be used to test general logic such as the flow of your code ond the logic of your query.

I personally always implement the first option to simulate an end-to-end test.  For the other test, I usually implement fixtures and mocks myself without any special library. The reason is that I do not know what is the confidence of a particulat mock library so I cannot know what is the confidence of my tests.